# CSS Nav content positioning

Tags: css, nav

I'm trying to get the `nav_right` section of the nav bar to align to the right but line up against the right hand edge of the `company name`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xXfV.png

I can set `.nav ul` to `24.5em` to line things up but on different screen sizes this doesn't work.

Here is the CSS:

```
    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.nav{
    width: auto;
    padding: 2em 0 0 0.5em;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.nav ul{
    width: 24.5em;
    font-family: "Century Gothic","Lucida Grande",Arial,sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li{    
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #fff;
 }
.nav b{
    font-weight: 900;
}
.nav li:hover{
    text-decoration: #000;
}

#nav_right{
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: right;
}

.triangle{
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 10px solid #000;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

img{
    float: right;
    width: 10%;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;

}

.main_wrapper{
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-top: 20%;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1em #000;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css" />
        <title>TEST</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li id="nav_right"><a href="#">HOME</a> | <a href="#about">ABOUT</a> | <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                    <a href="#"><li>company<b>name</b></li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try putting the `li` with the nav links after the company name `li` in the HTML and use `display:inline-block` to get them next to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does adding

```
nav li {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Do what you are looking for?

<kbd>[Example](http://jsbin.com/UNiTale/2)</kbd>

### Edit

To achieve what you want, you can remove the `width` declaration and instead declare `display: inline-block` on the `ul` element. The element will then stretch only to the width of its widest content (in this case your `li` containing the big **CompanyName**) instead of the whole width of the parent element.

Your other menu will then align to the right of the element as you wish.

So basically:

```
nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav li {
    text-align: right;
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://jsbin.com/UNiTale/5/)</kbd>

### P.S.

By the way, your markup is really weird, and you probably should refactor that. Your menu items are all enclosed in one single `<li>` while they should each be a separate element; you could then add the purely presentational `|` vertical bars through CSS.

Comment: Yes it does, but I would prefer it to not use
`.nav ul{
width: 24.5em;
}`
to align right to
but automatically use the width of company name

Comment: I see. Edited answer to meet your new requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can restructure your CSS and HTML to set a width for the `nav` class. Separate all your links into `li` and add styling that adds margin and a white line. This way, when you add more items, the style will automatically be applied to other list items.

This code will always align the menu to the right edge across all browsers. The only downside is that your list items have to be put backwards. From last to first because `float:right` is switching the order.

CSS:

```
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }

    nav {
        background: #000;
    }

    .nav {
        width: 24.5em;
        padding: 2em 0 0 0.5em;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
        font-family: "Century Gothic","Lucida Grande",Arial,sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

        .nav ul {
            text-align: right;
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        .nav a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: inherit;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .nav li {
            color: #fff;
            display: inline;
            padding: 0 6px;
            border-right: 1px solid #fff;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            font-weight: 600;
            float: right;
        }

            .nav li:first-child {
                padding-right: 0;
                border: none;
            }

            .nav li:last-child {
                padding-left: 0;
            }

        .nav #companyName {
            font-size: 3em;
            color: #fff;
        }

            .nav #companyName b {
                font-weight: 900;
            }

        .nav li:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }


    .triangle {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 10px solid #000;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
        border-left: 10px solid transparent;
        margin: auto;
        opacity: 0.4;
    }

    img {
        float: right;
        width: 10%;
        margin-top: 1em;
        margin-left: 1em;
        margin-right: 1em;
    }

    .main_wrapper {
        width: auto;
        height: 100px;
        margin-left: 1em;
        margin-top: 20%;
        overflow: hidden;
        float: left;
        background-color: #000;
        border-radius: 10px;
        opacity: 0.4;
        box-shadow: 0 0 1em #000;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css" />
        <title>TEST</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="companyName">
                    <a href="#">company<b>name</b></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

put the a tag with company name on the outside of the div called nav.

**HTML**

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css" />
            <title>TEST</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav>
              <a href="#" class="companyname"><li>company<b>name</b>
                <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="nav_right"><a href="#">HOME</a> | <a href="#about">ABOUT</a> |                <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS**

```
    nav {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden
   }
   .companyname {
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
   }

  .nav ul{
   display: inline-block;
   float: right
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
```